# Redirect Error in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have one website which was working perfectly then for adding meta tags and all, I have SEO-ULTIMATE plugin.

By mistake I have added Title, so my url also changed after it.

So to change it back to again what I have changed the direct url,

And then also it was not coming properly.

So i changed in redirection the new url was coming, So i changed to old one.

But then also its coming error "Redirection Loop Error".

Then i tired to remove that page which was giving problem.

And again created new page with the same name.

But now i m again trying to give the same url but its not able to give, and its coming like "page-2". but that also not able to retrive that page.

Comment: Just to make sure - you deleted the old page from the Trash, right? Because in order for the new page to get a permalink like `page-2`, that means that there is a permalink conflict, so WordPress adds `-n` to the permalink(where `n` is a number that doesn't conflict, starting from 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Nikola, I have tried the same.

I deleted page from trash and from the database also.

Now its working fine. Thanks for replay. :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/ I use it when I want to change specific post/page permalink. This should work for you too.